# How do I compare two columns and print non matching values in each dataframe?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to compare df1 and df2 and find the entry which are present df1 but not df2 and present in df2 but not in df1 in r.

```
Input:

df1 <- data.frame(ID1 = c("d", "p", "n", "m", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID2 = c("c", "b", "a", "d", "s", "p"))

Output:

nonMatch_Uniquedf1 <- data.frame(ID1 = c("n", "m"))
nonMatch_Uniquedf2 <- data.frame(ID2 = c("b", "a", "s"))
```

Please note that both columns of df1 and df2 have different row numbers.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **dplyr**:

```
require(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(!df1$ID1 %in% df2$ID2) #For df1 values not in df2
df2 %>% 
  filter(!df2$ID2 %in% df1$ID1) #For df2 values not in df1
```

Edit: with the expected output:

```
nonMatch_Uniquedf1 <- df1 %>% 
      filter(!df1$ID1 %in% df2$ID2) #For df1 values not in df2
nonMatch_Uniquedf2 <- df2 %>% 
      filter(!df2$ID2 %in% df1$ID1) #For df2 values not in df1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working. I little correction, since I updated the question so I am changing the object name in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way of reaching the desired output using the `anti_join` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  anti_join(df2, 
            # Define equivalence in column names in both df
            by = c("ID2" = "ID1"))
df2 %>%
  anti_join(df1, 
            # Define equivalence in column names in both df
            by = c("ID1" = "ID2"))
```